# Dropping balls in Javascript, not dropping one by one, instead all the balls dropped at once. (must be related to 'iterator')

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to make bell-curve visualization using D3.
Specifically, I wanted to show every single balls dropping movement one by one.

I saw an example in Observable. Since I'm studying D3, I tried to run things in my javascript code.
Original Observable code is as below:
https://observablehq.com/@cbuie/pachinko-simulator

I converted the code in javascript as below.

```js
var random = d3.randomNormal() // Try randomUniform?

const n = 2000
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = 400
const radius = 2
const dodge = dodger(radius * 2 + 1);
const margin = ({
  top: 0,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 10
});
const values = Float64Array.from({
  length: n
}, random);
const x = d3.scaleLinear(d3.extent(values), [margin.left, width - margin.right]);
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height).style('overflow', 'visible')
// var fillScale = d3.scaleSequentialLog(chroma.interpolateSinebow)

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


function dodger(radius) {
  const radius2 = radius ** 2;
  const bisect = d3.bisector(d => d.x);
  const circles = [];


  return function(x) {
    const l = bisect.left(circles, x - radius);
    const r = bisect.right(circles, x + radius);
    let y = 0;
    for (let i = l; i < r; ++i) {
      const {
        x: xi,
        y: yi
      } = circles[i];
      const x2 = (xi - x) ** 2;
      const y2 = (yi - y) ** 2;
      if (radius2 > x2 + y2) {
        y = yi + Math.sqrt(radius2 - x2) + 1e-6;
        i = l - 1;
        continue;
      }
    }
    circles.splice(bisect.left(circles, x, l, r), 0, {
      x,
      y
    }); //what is this?
    return y;
  };


}



for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (i % 5 === 0)
    svg.node();
  const cx = x(values[i]); // x(values[i]);->what is this?
  const cy = height - margin.bottom - dodge(cx) - radius - 1;

  svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", cx)
    .attr("cy", -400)
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    // .attr("fill","#9e0dd7") //purple
    .transition()
    .duration(650)
    .ease(d3.easeBounce)
    .attr("cy", cy);
}

svg.node();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Final result was same but my code doesn't show the movement of balls but just shows the final distribution of the balls at once like 'baam!'.
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with 'generator'or 'iterator' etc.

Can any one let me know how to fix it so that I could should the movement of the balls from the top to the bottom one by one like 'hour glass'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, and yes it is related to generator functions, plus having an interval timer to get the next generator value.

```js
function* gen() {
  var random = d3.randomNormal(); // Try randomUniform?

  const n = 2000;
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = 400;
  const radius = 2;
  const dodge = dodger(radius * 2 + 1);
  const margin = { top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10 };

  const values = Float64Array.from({ length: n }, random);

  const x = d3.scaleLinear(d3.extent(values), [
    margin.left,
    width - margin.right
  ]);
  const svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("overflow", "visible");

  // var fillScale = d3.scaleSequentialLog(chroma.interpolateSinebow)

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  function dodger(radius) {
    const radius2 = radius ** 2;
    const bisect = d3.bisector(d => d.x);
    const circles = [];

    return function(x) {
      const l = bisect.left(circles, x - radius);
      const r = bisect.right(circles, x + radius);
      let y = 0;
      for (let i = l; i < r; ++i) {
        const { x: xi, y: yi } = circles[i];
        const x2 = (xi - x) ** 2;
        const y2 = (yi - y) ** 2;
        if (radius2 > x2 + y2) {
          y = yi + Math.sqrt(radius2 - x2) + 1e-6;
          i = l - 1;
          continue;
        }
      }
      circles.splice(bisect.left(circles, x, l, r), 0, { x, y }); //what is this?
      return y;
    };
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (i % 5 === 0) yield svg.node();
    const cx = x(values[i]); // x(values[i]);->what is this?
    const cy = height - margin.bottom - dodge(cx) - radius - 1;

    svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", cx)
      .attr("cy", -400)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("fill", "#9e0dd7") //purple
      .transition()
      .duration(650)
      .ease(d3.easeBounce)
      .attr("cy", cy);
  }

  yield svg.node();
}


const genratorAnimation = gen(); 

let result = genratorAnimation.next();
//genratorAnimation.next();
let interval = setInterval(function(){
   if(!result.done) {
     genratorAnimation.next();
   }
   else {
    clearInterval(interval)
   }
}, 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really appreciate it!! I hate Observable too. I spent such an amount of time to figure that out but it was a good chance for me to study iterator, iterable and generator reading through the articles in "Medium". I kind of got a clear idea about what those are, I will look into your code to understand the details based on what I learnt yesterday and today in those articles. Really appreciate it, you saved my life.